# Windows 8: SQLlite or Application Resources

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, windows-8

I have a question regarding Local Storage and persistent data in Windows 8.

As I have to store some data in my app locally, I was wondering what is the best approach to develop it. I read everywhere that SQLite is a good choice for that, but I see in this tutorial 
["Create a blog reader"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx)
that the feeds data source are saved in the Application Local Resources, Application.Resources property.

Is this a good workaround? When to use one or the other?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To storage data you have ways:

1) SQL Lite  in local folder.

2) Application settings.

3) Local Files.

This feed sample collect data in Application.Resources.

When You have a lot of data and data types with relations use SQLLite.
When You have a data system without relations use local storage.

Answer (score 1):

When used properly, SQLite can serve as [excellent application data format](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

It has lots of benefits:

- Allows very fast access to large data sets (when proper indexes are created).
- Ensures transactional integrity of your data.
- Saved data can be easily inspected and debugged by using wide array of available open source and commercial tools.
- It is very easy to extend your storage format as your application evolves by simply adding new tables and/or columns. Often you can stay compatible with older versions of your database without much pain.
- ...

SQLite has become format of choice for pretty much anything mobile - Android, iOS, etc, store almost everything except for media and program binaries in SQLite.

But even for desktop applications, SQLite is also becoming format of choice.
For example, Mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird store pretty much everything - bookmarks, history, emails, etc. in SQLite databases. Same goes for Google Chrome and [many, many other apps](http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html).

Decision is yours, but if used properly, SQLite can be wicked fast and extremely easy to use for developers.